# Jquery PHP echo dynamic data

Tags: php, jquery, post, input, echo

I have a Jquery post script, which for reasons outside of my control has to be placed on a page by use of echo from PHP. Now the issue is that I need to pass information from a form on the page into the data to be posted.

Here is the working script at the moment:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(".discuss_your_report").click( function() {
    $.post(\'/layout/standard/report-action.php\', {
        form: "discuss_your_report", website: "'.$_GET['website'].'", name: "'.$_GET['name'].'", email: "'.$_GET['email'].'", phone: ""},
        function(data){
            $(".message").html(data);
    $(".message").show("slow");
        }
    );
</script>';
```

In the above script the phone number is empty, this needs to be entered by the user in the page using a standard form input. I have tried many things that have not worked, this being the latest:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(".discuss_your_report").click( function() {
    var phone = $(\'#phone\').val();
    $.post(\'/layout/standard/report-action.php\', {
        form: "discuss_your_report", website: "'.$_GET['website'].'", name: "'.$_GET['name'].'", email: "'.$_GET['email'].'", phone: "phone"},
        function(data){
            $(".message").html(data);
    $(".message").show("slow");
        }
    );
</script>';
```

For ease of readibility, here it is without the PHP code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".discuss_your_report").click( function() {
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    $.post('/layout/standard/report-action.php', {
        form: "discuss_your_report", website: "www.example.com", name: "my name", email: "info@example.com", phone: "phone"},
    function(data){
    $(".message").html(data);
    $(".message").show("slow");
    }
);
</script>
```

But this just passes the text 'phone'. Does anyone know how I can get this to work, any feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have changed var phone to phone_val, have assigned it with phone: phone_val without quote

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(".discuss_your_report").click( function() {
    var phone_val = $(\'#phone\').val();
    $.post(\'/layout/standard/report-action.php\', {
        form: "discuss_your_report", website: "'.$_GET['website'].'", name: "'.$_GET['name'].'", email: "'.$_GET['email'].'", phone: phone_val},
        function(data){
            $(".message").html(data);
    $(".message").show("slow");
        }
    );
</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It sorted the problem with passing the variable, but it would appear this 'var phone_val = $("#phone").val();' is not getting the value from the input.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".discuss_your_report").click( function() {
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    $.post('/layout/standard/report-action.php', {
        form: "discuss_your_report", 
        website: "www.example.com", 
        name: "my name", 
        email: "info@example.com", 
        phone: phone},
    function(data){
    $(".message").html(data);
    $(".message").show("slow");
    }
);
</script>
```

"phone" - this is text

phone - is variable

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dynamic reference to the form element at the time of posting:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(".discuss_your_report").click( function() {
    var phone = $(\'#phone\').val();
    $.post(\'/layout/standard/report-action.php\', {
        form: "discuss_your_report", website: "'.$_GET['website'].'", name: "'.$_GET['name'].'", email: "'.$_GET['email'].'", phone: document.forms.discuss_your_report.phone.value },
        function(data){
            $(".message").html(data);
    $(".message").show("slow");
        }
    );
</script>';
```

Comment: I updated my post so that it works in-line (without creating any unnecessary local vars as the posters above do)